# What is truly unbreakable these days?

Tags: passwords, cryptography, databases

Just very curious, count my knowledge in cryptography, algorithms, and security in general as non-existent. Now I am aware that this might be a VERY broad question, but here it goes. What is the most secure and virtually unbreakable cryptography to secure data in today's standards (and of course tomorrow's). Tips and tricks to keep the hackers and THOSEWHOWESHALLNOTNAME at bay?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Everything is unbreakable until it isn't. Knowing whether a system will ever be broken in the future requires more knowledge than simply can't be had today.

But to the best of our knowledge, all evidence suggests that today's commercial encryption (RSA, ECC, AES, .etc) is, in fact, unbreakable. That includes digital signatures, secure web traffic, consumer tools like truecrypt and 7-zip, and many of the things you use every day. As far as we know, they are impossible for anyone, from your neighbor to your NSA, to break....

Unless you count brute-force password guessing, side-channel attacks, and other forms of circumvention:

[image: XKCD Security]

And that's the point -- there's *always* a weak point somewhere. Security can't be perfect. But the weak point isn't the cryptography. Instead it's the fact that your password is your girlfriend's dog's name spelled backwards. Or the fact that you stored a second copy of the document on Dropbox. Or the fact that a spy camera was recently installed in your ceiling.

Modern encryption is either *completely unbreakable*, or *unbreakable enough*. There really is no practical distinction between the two concepts, nor would you ever really be able to tell them apart.

Comment: I would consider the fact that in the second picture they got a wrench to get the answer, the encryption did it's job. That comic was actually funny. but another question arises, if these systems are so secure, how do people such as "your neighbor to your NSA" get all the information then? From what i heard Brute-force takes too long, and Side Channel attacking sometimes leads to dead ends... sorry, this is quite a bit to understand, security is quite interesting.

Comment: @n9Beast Most stuff isn't encrypted. Some stuff is poorly encrypted. Some encryption standards (GSM) were deliberately crippled in the standards process to make interception possible. Sometimes they go to a company like Microsoft and ask nicely, sometimes they ask not-so-nicely and legally compel companies to give up their encryption keys. There's plenty of ways to get what you want when you have unlimited authority and legal latitude.

Answer (score 2):

The only "unbreakable" encryption technique is a [one-time pad](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-time_pad). There are several problems with this, of course.

From the wiki:

- it requires perfectly random one-time pads, which is a non-trivial software requirement.
- secure generation and exchange of the one-time pad material, which must be at least as long as the message.
- careful treatment to make sure that it continues to remain secret from any adversary, and is disposed of correctly preventing any reuse in whole or part — hence "one time".

Comment: Thank you for the answer (so quick) I'll look up the One-Time pad, so if you will so kindly answer this, say I would want to, implement this in an app, is this possible? If this is the only "unbreakable" crypt. why aren't the big boys using it? such as Facebook and the likes, does snapchat use such a technique? Or are they?

Comment: @n9beast The problem with one-time pads is that you need at least as much key-data as the actual data you want to exchange. And the key-data needs to be exchanged via a secure channel before the encrypted data can be exchanged.